# Installanywhere Openjdk 1.7.0_111

Tags: redhat, java, installanywhere

i have a problem.

i'm using installanywhere for some product. (installanywhere 2014 SP1)

1. setting installanywhere option,

Product > JVM Settings > VM valid List : JDK_1.7+, IBM_JDK_1.7+
this option installer choose openjdk.

2. i'm success install in openjdk 1.7.0_65, redhat 6.x 64bit os.
       but install failed in openjdk 1.7.0_111, redbat 6.x 64bit os.
3. error message -

   ```
   ===============================================================================
   This Test installer                             (created with InstallAnywhere)
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   Preparing CONSOLE Mode Installation...


   This installer was created with an unlicensed version 
   of InstallAnywhere.  The evaluation period has expired. 
   Please contact sales@flexerasoftware.com about licensing.
   ```

so, commanding [export LAX_DEBUG=true]  and install.

under line debug message.

```
    Preparing to install...
    Checking for POSIX df.
    Found POSIX df.
    Checking tail options...
    Using tail -n 1.
    True location of the self extractor: /opt/Test/Test_Setup_RedHat.bin
    Forcing install base (including tmp dir) to: /opt/Test/tmp
    Creating installer data directory: /opt/Test/tmp/install.dir.27084
    Creating installer data directory: /opt/Test/tmp/install.dir.27084/InstallerData
    Gathering free-space information...
    Space needed to complete the self-extraction: 16376 blocks
    Available space: 242730896 blocks
    Available blocks: 242730896    Needed blocks: 16376 (block = 512 bytes)
    This installation does not contain a VM.
    Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
    Extracting install.zip from ./Test_Setup_RedHat.bin to /opt/Test/tmp/install.dir.27084/InstallerData/installer.zip ...
    Extracting to padded done, exit code = 0
    Extracting from padded to zip done, exit code = 0
    Creating disk1 data directory: /opt/Test/tmp/install.dir.27084/InstallerData/Disk1
    Creating instdata data directory: /opt/Test/tmp/install.dir.27084/InstallerData/Disk1/InstData
    Extracting resources from ./Test_Setup_RedHat.bin to /opt/Test/tmp/install.dir.27084/InstallerData/Disk1/InstData/Resource1.zip ...
    Extracting done, exit code = 0
    Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

    [7m========= Analyzing UNIX Environment =================================[0m
    Setting UNIX (linux) flavor specifics.
    Importing UNIX environment into LAX properties.
    Checking for POSIX awk.

    [7m========= Analyzing LAX ==============================================[0m
    LAX found............................ OK.
    LAX properties read.................. OK.

    [7m========= Finding VM =================================================[0m
    [1mValid VM types.......................... JDK_1.7+, IBM_JDK_1.7+[0m
    [1mExpanded Valid VM types.................  JDK_1.7+,  IBM_JDK_1.7+ [0m
    Found jvmspecs.properties
    JVM Spec Build Option Specified Without VM
    Searching without JVM specs
    Searching without JVM specs
    [1mWARNING! No valid lax.nl.current.vm available.[0m
    /usr/xpg4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/cfengine/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin
    [1mSearching for VMs in PATH:[0m
    Looking in:............................. /usr/xpg4/bin
    Looking in:............................. /usr/local/bin
    Looking in:............................. /bin
    Looking in:............................. /usr/bin
      Found VM:............................. /usr/bin/java
       Version:............................. 1.7.0_111
    Looking in:............................. /usr/local/sbin
    Looking in:............................. /usr/sbin
    Looking in:............................. /sbin
    Looking in:............................. /var/cfengine/bin
    Looking in:............................. /bin
    Looking in:............................. /usr/bin
      Found VM:............................. /usr/bin/java
       Version:............................. 1.7.0_111
    Looking in:............................. /sbin
    Looking in:............................. /usr/sbin
    Looking in:............................. /usr/local/bin
    checking: "1.7.0_111" against "JDK_1.7+,": failed (wrong version)
    checking: "1.7.0_111" against "JDK_1.7+,": failed (wrong version)
    checking: "1.7.0_111" against "IBM_JDK_1.7+": passed
    [1m Using VM:............................. /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java[0m

    [7m========= Virtual Machine Options ====================================[0m
    LAX properties incorporated............. OK.
    classpath............................... "/opt/Test/tmp/install.dir.27084/InstallerData:/opt/Test/tmp/install.dir.27084/InstallerData/installer.zip"
    main class.............................. "com.zerog.ia.installer.Main"
    .lax file path.......................... "/opt/Test/tmp/install.dir.27084/temp.lax"
    user directory.......................... "/opt/Test/tmp/install.dir.27084"
    stdout to............................... "console"
    sterr to................................ "console"
    install directory....................... ""
    JIT..................................... none
    option (verify)......................... off
    option (verbosity)...................... none
    option (garbage collection extent)...... none
    option (garbage collection thread)...... none
    option (native stack max size).......... none
    option (java stack max size)............ none
    option (java heap max size)............. 50331648
    option (java heap initial size)......... 16777216
    option (lax.nl.java.option.additional).. none

    [7m========= Display settings ===========================================[0m
    X display............................... not set
    [1mWARNING:  This shell's DISPLAY variable has not been set.
    This installer is  configured to run in GUI and will probably
    fail.  Try running this  installer in console or silent mode,
    or on another  UNIX  host which has the DISPLAY variable set,
    if the installer unexpectedly fails.[0m
    UI mode................................. gui

    Launching installer...

    [7m========= VM Command Line ============================================[0m
    [1moptions:[0m   
    [7mCLASSPATH:[0m/opt/Test/tmp/install.dir.27084/InstallerData:/opt/Test/tmp/install.dir.27084/InstallerData/installer.zip:

    [7m========= Forking JAVA =============================================[0m
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file:
       27084
    Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.

    ===============================================================================
    This Test installer                             (created with InstallAnywhere)
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Preparing CONSOLE Mode Installation...


    This installer was created with an unlicensed version 
    of InstallAnywhere.  The evaluation period has expired. 
    Please contact sales@flexerasoftware.com about licensing.
```

what should i do? success running open jdk 1.7.0_65, but open jdk 1.7.0_111 failed.

CentOS 6.2 and OpenJDK1.7.0_111 running success.

Comment: hello. i found this problem.

Comment: See this, 1. https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/SERVER-1456/SERVER-1456.html

Comment: 2. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1361818

Comment: OpenJDK1.7.0_111 SunEC error. my installer custom code use SunEC. if you using OpenJDK1.7.0_111 and Custom code SunEC, then      yum upgrade nss